# AuthJS / NextAuth "504 Gateway Time-Out" on Vercel but works on localhost for Next.JS 13 App Router

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth, next.js13

I've been trying to deploy my NextJS app on Vercel for the last few days, but have gotten nowhere because my AuthJS route (`/api/auth/signin`) hangs once I put in an email (using email provider) and hit submit. This route works fine on my localhost. The Vercel logs don't show any errors and just show that the function was hit on `/api/auth/signin` so I am in the dark about what is causing it to hang. Would greatly appreciate any suggestions on either what I can do to debug this or what is causing this.